# Change the font family with a shortcut in XTerm

Tags: terminal, fonts, xterm

I'm trying to change the font family on the fly (with a shortcut) in XTerm. At the moment I can change the font size. I tried to do this with the action `set-render-font()`, but I'm not sure if it's the right action.

This is my code:

```
xterm*VT100.Translations: #override \
    Ctrl <Key>V: insert-selection(CLIPBOARD) \n\
    Ctrl <Key>C: copy-selection(CLIPBOARD) \n\
    Ctrl <Key>H: smaller-vt-font() \n\
    Ctrl <Key>L: larger-vt-font() \n\
    Ctrl <Key>R: set-vt-font(d) \n\
    Ctrl Alt <Key>1: set-render-font("DejaVu Sans Mono for Powerline")
```

The last line is the one I want to fix.

Edit: I'm discovering that probably `load-vt-fonts` could work. However I can't make it work, since I don't know how to indicate the font family.

Edit2: I've been able to input a command to change the background color of the terminal (sequence `11;`), but this is not working to change the font family (sequence `50;`). Code:

```
...
Ctrl Alt <Key>1: interpret("\033]11;#112233\007") \n\
Ctrl Alt <Key>2: interpret("\033]50;DejaVu Sans Mono for Powerline\007")
```

Comment: [`set-render-font`](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#Actions:set-render-font) parameter is *on*, *off* or *toggle*.  no fontname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution:

```
interpret("\033]50;xft:Terminess Powerline\007")
```

It works for URxvt and XTerm. Now I will be able to make some commands to switch typographies on the fly!

To make it work with XTerm, it needs the following option enabled:

```
xterm*allowFontOps: true
```